# how to read the binary section of script currently being evaluated?

Tags: tcl

How do I read the section after end-of-stream (`^Z`) in a Tcl-script being sourced?

So far I got `info script` returning the filename of the currently sourced script which I could `open` just like any file and put the read position to after end-of-stream by just parsing the file.

In theory the content of the file could change between the invocation of `source` and subsequent `info script` and `open`, possibly causing temporal inconsistency between read script and binary data.

Is there a magic command for this that I've missed? Or do we rely on users/administrators making sure such inconsistencies can't happen?

Comment: No real magic. Just read until you can't after setting the channel's `-eofchar`, either with one big `read` or a loop with `gets` (the latter is more suited for when dealing with a large file).

Comment: @DonalFellows Not sure what you mean... If I run `tclsh` on script `foo.tcl` which has a binary section I can't seem to find a way to read the exact same file as `tclsh`. Using `open` from within `foo.tcl` would open a possibly different file, should it be rewritten between invocation of `tclsh` and invoking `open` from within the script. I would assume there is some way to "clone" the channel/file `tclsh` got from opening `foo.tcl`. Am I making sense?

Comment: The internals implementing `source` close the channel before evaluating the script. So, there is no way to get a hold on that very channel from within that script, I am afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Suggestion

Provide for your custom `source` that extracts the trailer in the same I/O step as sourcing the contained script. For example:

```
interp hide {} source source
proc ::source {fp} {
  set size [file size $fp]
  set chan [open $fp r]
  info script $fp
  try {
    chan configure $chan -eofchar {\u001a {}}
    set script [read $chan]
    uplevel 1 [list eval $script]
    set scriptOffset [chan tell $chan]
    if {$scriptOffset < $size} {
      chan seek $chan 1 current; # move cursor beyond eof
      chan configure $chan -translation binary
      set trailer [read $chan]
      # do whatever you want to do with the trailer
    }
  } finally {
    close $chan
  }
}
```

### Some remarks

- The trick is to employ the same machinery as Tcl's `source` does internally: `configure -eofchar`.
- Once it has been determined, that there is a trailer (i.e., content beyond the eof char), `seek` is used to position the cursor at the script's offset.
- A second `read` will then get you the trailer.
- From this point onwards, you must be careful to maintain the trailer value in its shape as byte array.

Disclaimer: Tcl wizards like Donal might have better ways of doing so. Also, single-file distribution mechanisms like starkits might have helpers for dealing with script trailers.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `string bytelength`; the meaning of that is very much not related to the content of the file other than coincidentally. (It's the length of Tcl's _internal_ encoding; I'd bet good money that you've never need precisely that, especially not when dealing with I/O.) There's `chan tell` for saying how many bytes you've read from a channel (or rather where the read cursor is; it's the same thing when you've not used `chan seek` yet). Also, `-translation binary` implies `-encoding binary`.

Comment: Also, you should advance the read position one byte so that it is after the ^Z, and you forgot the setting of `info script`, which quite a few scripts rely on to find other resources…

Comment: @DonalFellows Thx for the review, changed accordingly.

Comment: however, as it stands, it is surely not a full replacement for the built-in `source` (`return` handling and so).

Comment: I also figured that one does not have to reset the eofchar when using `-translation binary`.

Comment: I did not consider wrapper-like solutions. That opens up the mind a little, giving room for better solutions. Thanks :)